# Probability and Addition help

Tags: probability

On Wednesday the weather forecast for Thursday was 60% chance of rain and a 35% 
chance of rain on Friday.  If there is a 20% chance of rain for both Thursday and Friday, what is the probability that there will be rain on Thursday or Friday?

I don't know how to figure this problem out.

Comment: Find the probability $P$ it with *not* rain on both Thursday and Friday, then your desired answer is $1-P$.

Comment: So would that be 80% that it wouldn't rain on Thursday and Friday?

Comment: Nope.  Not rain Thursday:  $1 - 60\% = 40\% = .4$.  Not rain Friday:  $1 - 35\% = 65\% = .65$.  Not rain BOTH days:  $.4 \times .65$.

Comment: wouldn't the answer be 60/100 + 35/100 -20/100 because it's adding the probability of it raining for each day and then subtracting the probability of it raining on both days?

Comment: If it rains on Thursday AND Friday, then it has rained on Thursday OR Friday.  (Think about it.)

Comment: If rains on both days then it rains on both days. Not one or the other.

Comment: You should check an elementary logic book on **OR**:   (True **OR** True) implies True.  You're describing the **exclusive-OR**:  A or B but not both.

Comment: @David Your statement "Not rain BOTH days: .4×.65" assumes independence but the events are not independent.

Comment: @Glen-b:  You are correct.  Either I mis-read the question or it was altered later.  So the non-independence must be considered.  Sorry for the mixup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ be the event of rain on Thursday, and $F$ be the event of rain on Friday.

In general, we have the inclusion-exclusion law:

$$P(A \cup B ) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

So, applied to this case:

$$P(T \cup F) = P(T) + P(F) - P(T \cap F) = 0.6 + 0.35 - 0.2 = 0.75$$